# expression cannot be used as a function :error

Tags: c++

```
#include<iomanip>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
double lenght;
lenght=(3(sqrt(3)/2))*(pow(2,2));

return length;
}
```

why I am getting
error: expression cannot be used as a function

Comment: 3(...) is not a valid expression

Comment: There are multiple errors in this. 1) In the 8th line, `(3(sqrt(3)/2))` is wrong. I guess what you want is `(3*(sqrt(3)/2))`. 2) The `length` variable is undefined at line 10. Changing it with `lenght` or changing the above two `lenght` to `length` would correct the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the `*` operator in the expression `3(sqrt(3)/2))` .

Also, since your `main` function is of type `int` , `return (int)lenght;`

```
#include<iomanip>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double lenght;
    lenght = (3*(sqrt(3) / 2)) * (pow(2, 2));
    

    return (int)lenght;
}
```

Comment: The returned value will be cast to an `int` anyway, there's no need to do a manual cast, especially a c-style cast.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
lenght=(3*(sqrt(3)/2))*(pow(2,2)));
```